# How do I change old Image to New image by using graphene-django?

Tags: django-rest-framework, graphene-django

I want to change an old image to a new image by using graphene-django.

In my database, there is one picture that has and id of 1.
I want to change the picture, that means I want to make a new picture that has an id of 1.

This is my mutation:

```
class ImageAndSelfMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        image = Upload()

    Output = types.EditProfileResponse

    def mutate(self, info, image, **kwargs):
        user = info.context.user
        ok = True
        error = None

        if user.is_authenticated is not None:
            try:
                first_image = models.Photo.objects.get(owner=user, order="first")
                create_image = models.Photo.objects.create(image=image[0], owner=user)

                serializer = serializers.ImageSerializer(first_image, data=create_image)

                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save(owner=user)

            return types.EditProfileResponse(ok=ok, error=error)
        else:
            error = '로그인이 필요합니다.'
            return types.EditProfileResponse(ok=not ok, error=error)
```

This code makes some new data that has an id of 2, but I don't want to make new data. I want to change the id of 1's picture.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Changing id of instance is bad idea. New id values should be generated by sequence in database. Instead of changing id you can duplicate previous instance with new image and then delete previous one:

```
previous_id = first_image.id
first_image.id = None
first_image.image = image[0]
first_image.save()
models.Photo.objects.filter(id=previous_id).delete()
```